# Python - How to get the filename in tkinter file dialog

Tags: python

I am trying to get just the file name of the selected file in tkinter file dialog

Here's my code:

```
def browseFile(self):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Video files", "*.mp4;*.flv;*.avi;*.mkv"),
                                       ("All files", "*.*") ))

    print file_path
```

What I am getting with this code is the whole path of the selected file, where I only need the file name. How can I do it?

results
with my code:

```
 C:/Users/Guest/vid1.mp4
```

what I want:

```
 vid1.mp4
```

Comment: see [os.path.split](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.split)

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> import os
>>> s = "C:/Users/Guest/vid1.mp4"
>>> os.path.split(s)
('C:/Users/Guest', 'vid1.mp4')
>>> os.path.split(s)[1]
'vid1.mp4'
```

Alternatively,

```
>>> os.path.basename(s)
'vid1.mp4'
```

Comment: yup same results but is there any way like file_path.name() other than splitting strings?

Comment: No, there's no method belonging to the `file_path` object that will find the name for you. It's an ordinary string object, and doesn't even know it contains a filename.